# Bytecode optimization

Tags: python

Here are 2 simple examples. In the first example `append` method produces LOAD_ATTR instruction inside the cycle, in the second it only produced once and result saved in variable (ie cached). *Reminder: I remember, that there `extend` method for this task which is much faster that this*

```
setup = \
"""LIST = []
ANOTHER_LIST = [i for i in range(10**7)]

def appender(list, another_list):
    for elem in another_list:
        list.append(elem)

def appender_optimized(list, another_list):
    append_method = list.append
    for elem in another_list:
        append_method(elem)"""


import timeit

print(timeit.timeit("appender(LIST, ANOTHER_LIST)", setup=setup, number=10))
print(timeit.timeit("appender_optimized(LIST, ANOTHER_LIST)", setup=setup, number=10))
```

Results:

```
11.92684596051036
7.384205785584728
```

4.6 seconds difference (even for such a big list) is no joke - for my opinion such difference can not be counted as "micro optimization". Why Python does not do it for me? Because bytecode must be exact reflection of source code? Do compiler even optimize anything? For example,

```
def te():
    a = 2
    a += 1
    a += 1
    a += 1
    a += 1
```

produces

```
LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
INPLACE_ADD
STORE_FAST               0 (a)
```

4 times instead of optimize into a += 4. Or do it optimize some famous things like producing bit shift instead of multiplying by 2? Am I misunderstand something about basic language concepts?

Comment: Just theorizing the `append_method = list.append` skips a bunch of redundant checks (eg `__getattribute__`) against the list object (Python objects all behave like dicts to an extent).    I bet if you cut your test list size down and divide time/size you can find the microsend cost of each lookup to get append from the list object.

Comment: Yeah, it do exactly this. The question is why compiler does not do it automatically?

Comment: Cpython is intended to be the reference build so it doesn't have a JIT or optimizing virtual machine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python is a dynamic language.  This means that you have *a lot* of freedom in how you write code.  Due to the crazy amounts of introspection that python exposes (which are incredibly useful BTW), many optimizations simply cannot be performed.  For example, in your first example, python has no way of knowing what datatype `list` is going to be when you call it.  I could create a really weird class:

```
class CrazyList(object):
    def append(self, value):
        def new_append(value):
            print "Hello world"

        self.append = new_append
```

Obviously this isn't useful, but I *can* write this and it *is* valid python.  If I were to pass this type to your above function, the code would be different than the version where you "cache" the `append` function.

We could write a similar example for `+=` (it could have side-effects that wouldn't get executed if the "compiler" optimized it away).

In order to optimize efficiently, python would have to know your types ... And for a vast majority of your code, it has no (fool-proof) way to get the type data so it doesn't even try for most optimizations.

---

Please note that this *is* a micro optimization (and a [well documented](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/) one).  It is useful in some cases, but in most cases it is unnecessary if you write idiomatic python.  e.g. your `list` example is best written using the `.extend` method as you've noted in your post.  Most of the time, if you have a loop that is tight enough for the lookup time of a method to matter in your overall program runtime, then either you should find a way to rewrite just that loop to be more efficient or even push the computation into a faster language (e.g. `C`).  Some libraries are *really* good at this (`numpy`).

---

With that said, there are some optimizations that *can* be done safely by the "compiler" in a stage known as the "peephole optimizer".  e.g. It will do some simple constant folding for you:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def foo():
...     a = 5 * 6
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               3 (30)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

In some cases, it'll cache values for later use, or turn one type of object into another:

```
>>> def translate_tuple(a):
...   return a in [1, 3]
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(translate_tuple)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_CONST               3 ((1, 3))
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

(Note the list got turned into a `tuple` and cached -- In python3.2+ `set` literals can also get turned into `frozenset` and cached).

Comment: I don't think you could write a similar example for the `a += 1` one. I don't blame the writers of Python for not trying to optimise this, but in theory there's nothing preventing it.

Comment: @AlexHall -- Not given that `a = 2` -- But if `a` was an unknown type, it'd be really easy.  Just write an `__iadd__` function with a side-effect.  If the compiler optimized it, it would be executed only once instead of 4 times.

Answer (score 2):

In general Python optimises virtually nothing. It won't even optimise trivial things like `x = x`. Python is so dynamic that doing so correctly would be extremely hard. For example the `list.append` method can't be automatically cached in your first example because it could be changed in another thread, something which can't be done in a more static language like Java.

Comment: The thread example doesn't really hold water, the relative ordering of events is nondeterministic anyway. If you wanted to actually force this madness to happen you'd have to insert some locking primitive, which could act as a barrier for optimization exactly as happens in other languages.

Comment: Please note that even if optimization is not trivial it is not impossible. PyPy includes some of these optimizations CPython doesn't do: https://morepypy.blogspot.com/2011/10/more-compact-lists-with-list-strategies.html

Comment: @MatteoItalia what do you mean?